# How to compare the case of two strings in Clojure?

Tags: string, clojure, case-sensitive

I have a Clojure function `autocomplete` that takes in a prefix and returns the possible `autocompletion` of that string. For example, if the input is `abs`, I get `absolute` as the possible complete word.

The problem is that the function does a case-insentitive match for the prefix so if I have `Abs` as the prefix input, I still get `absolute` instead of `Absolute`.

What would be the correct way to get the final string completion that matches the case of the original prefix entered?

So, a function `case-match` that could work like

```
(case-match "Abs" "absolute")  => "Absolute"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the *prefix* string as the prefix to the case-insensitive search result. Just use `subs` to drop the length of the prefix from the search result:

```
(defn case-match [prefix s]
  (str prefix (subs s (count prefix))))

(case-match "Abs" "absolute")
=> "Absolute"
```

This assumes your `autocomplete` function stays separate, and `case-match` would be applied to its result.

Answer (score 0):

also, you can go with `startsWith`

```
(defn case-match
  [prefix s]
  (when (.startsWith (clojure.string/lower-case s)
                     (clojure.string/lower-case prefix))
       s))

(case-match "Abs" "absolute")
#=> "absolute"
(case-match "Absence" "absolute")
#=> nil
```